# OpenXML - left table border doesn't work?

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

Here is my border formatting for creating a test table in a docx using OpenXML (C#):

```
    //Create a TableProperties object and specify its border information.
    var borderType = BorderValues.Single;
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.UInt32Value size = 5;
    TableProperties tblProp = new TableProperties(
        new TableJustification() { Val = TableRowAlignmentValues.Center },
        new TableBorders(
            new TopBorder(){ Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(borderType), Size = size },
            new BottomBorder(){ Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(borderType), Size = size },
            new LeftBorder(){ Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(borderType), Size = size },
            new RightBorder(){ Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(borderType), Size = size },
            new InsideHorizontalBorder(){ Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(borderType), Size = size },
            new InsideVerticalBorder(){ Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(borderType), Size = size }
        )
    );

    // Append the TableProperties object to the empty table.
    table.AppendChild<TableProperties>(tblProp);
```

The above formatting produces this (when viewed in 365 word viewer):
[image]

  The question is, why?

Here is the generated xml (extracted from zip):
[image]

EDIT: it renders correctly in the word desktop app.. so this seems to be a #Microsoft bug.

Answer (score 1):

Different clients often support the specification to different degrees. I remember fighting this when I was trying to produce content for Google docs.

There are some things you can try.

Firstly, instead of using `LeftBorder` and `RightBorder`, try `StartBorder` and `EndBorder`. These are important to support semantic considerations in RTL cultures vs. LTR cultures, and may consequently be better supported.

Secondly, reverse engineering nearly always worked for me. Start by styling a document how you want it to look in Word or other tools, then extract and examine the XML.

I think you'll find that Word defines a style that it applies to the table instead of trying to do it all inline - copying that approach is more complex, but often does the trick.